# Google map works fine on local but doesn't show on web server

Tags: api, maps

I have a site that contains google maps api v3 with markers according to the research options.
on the localhost it worked perfectly but the map doesn't load at all on server (online)
anyone has solved this problem before?

Comment: check your server log if all the files got loaded, or check this on the client side.

Comment: @Cerveser thank you for your comment but all files are loaded on server! i think there's a problem with the javascript code!! but if it's working on local why it doesn't even load online!!!

Comment: Clean the browser cache to make sure the exact same files are loaded. Also the script needs acces online to the googleapis.com URL